# Effect not significant in lmer which was significant in lm - interpretation

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, lm

I have a normal linear model (`lm(y ~ x + z)`) and a linear mixed model (`lmer(y ~ x + z + (1|id)`). `x` is continuous, `z` is a treatment dummy.

What does it mean if `z` is significant in the normal lm model, but not significant in the linear mixed model?

My intuition is: Since the random intercept models the variance associated with the factor `id`, this should mean that the variance explained by `z` and therefore its importance shrinks when taking into account the variability in intercepts in `id`. This would mean that the treatment (`z`) does not have an effect since its effect is negligible compared to the variance between the different levels of `id`. Am I correct, somewhat correct, or totally wrong here?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a plausible explanation.